# Using csv module to write file

Tags: python, csv, null

I'm trying to extract series numbers (that is the number of bus stops) from a csv file and write in a new csv file. These series numbers usually take the form as follows: "Queen Street, Bus Station - Platform A3 [BT000998]". I only need the content enclosed by the brackets. I found that there are cases that unwanted comma exist (as the example above), and using csv module can avoid such issue. In order to do that I wrote the following code:

```
import csv
import re
fp = open(r'C:\data\input.csv')
fpw = open(r'C:\data\output.csv','w')
data = csv.reader(fp)
writer = csv.writer(fpw)


for row in data:
    line = ','.join(row)
    lst = line.split(',')
    try:
        stop = lst[11]   # find the location that contains stop number
        extr = re.search(r"\[([A-Za-z0-9_]+)\]", stop)  # extract stop number enclosed by brackets
        stop_id = str(extr.group(1))
        lst[11] = stop_id  # replace the original content with the extracted stop number
        writer.writerow(lst) # write in the output file (fpw)
    except Exception, e:  # this part is in case there is error such as AttributeError
        writer.writerow(row)
```

After running this code, while there is no error raised, only an empty csv file is generated. I'm quite new to python. Much appreciate if anyone can help me with this code to make it work.

Thank you in advance.
Sui

====UPDATE====

Based on everyone's reply, I revised the code as follows:

```
import csv
import re
fp = r'C:\data\input.csv'
fpw = r'C:\data\output.csv'

with open(fp, 'rb') as input, open(fpw, 'wb') as output:
               for row in csv.reader(input):
                   try:
                       stop = row[11]
                       extr = re.search(r"\[([A-Za-z0-9_]+)\]", stop)
                       stop_id = str(extr.group(1))
                       row[11] = stop_id
                       repl_row = ','.join(row) + '\n'
                       output.write(repl_row)
                   except csv.Error:
                       pass
```

Now running the code seems working. HOWEVER, in the middle of running, an error 'line contains NULL byte' was raised, and python stopped even though I added try/except as shown above. So anyone has suggestion to deal with this issue and the let the code continue? By the way, the csv file I'm working on is over 2GB.

Many thanks, Sui

Comment: If there are commas in a field of a CSV file, the field needs to be enclodes in quotes. But if you just need the data in brackets, why do you need to read it as a CSV? Just read it as a plain text file and parse the brackets.

Comment: As per the csv module docs, you need to use `rb` and `wb` when opening the files.  This matters on Windows in particular.

Comment: Also, don't use exceptions to check if your regex matched.  Just say `if extr:` to test the result.

Comment: Hi Barmar, thanks for the reply. The reason is that when I read data as plain text file, the 'try' part may focus on the wrong field. For example, for rows that don't have extra commas, the total number of fields by comma is 15. But for those that have extra commas, as the above example, the total number of fields would be 16. AND the field of the bus stop number is 12 instead of 11. In that case, the result would be wrong for these rows.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for the comments. Do you suggest to change the code to this: data = csv.reader(fp, rb/wb)?

Comment: Hi Barmar, sorry for being unclear. I add some comments to the code, please note that I need to replace the original stop number field with the extracted number as well as the data of the other fields.

Answer (score 0):

If that's the whole code, you need to close the file with `fpw.close()` after you are done with all the `writer` operations.

You can also try `with` keyword, as in [official Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#examples)

Comment: Hi Serpens, thanks for the suggestion. Will have a go.